# Android Studio - Could not download artifact

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio IDE. I have created a sample project using Android Studio and when I tried to build it, it comes with the following error.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'SampleApp".
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download artifact 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48:bcprov-jdk15on.jar': No     
     cached version available for offline mode
```

Can anyone please figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It needs to download that library in order to do your build, but you've (perhaps inadvertantly) put Android Studio into offline mode. To fix it, go to Preferences > Gradle and ensure that the "Offline work" checkbox is not checked.

Comment: In windows `Preferences > Gradle` is located at `File > Settings > Gradle`

Answer (score 4):

I think you should add following code at the top level of your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()}
```

You might also need to try with --refresh-dependencies.
You can take more help from this [here](https://github.com/MEDvision/medrecord/tree/master/java#building-with-gradle).

Comment: even better, add `jcenter()` instead of `mavenCentral()`. That's the default for new projects in Android Studio cause it has more artifacts, faster resolution and generally better.